# combining 2 pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,1],[4,15,11],[7,22,15]],columns=['Start','End','Duration'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0,2,3],[1,2,2],[1,8,9],[2,1,1],[2,1,1]],columns=['Index','Data1','Data2'])

df
Out[6]: 
   Start  End  Duration
0      1    2         1
1      4   15        11
2      7   22        15

df2
Out[7]: 
   Index  Data1  Data2
0      0      2      3
1      1      2      2
2      1      8      9
3      2      1      1
4      2      1      1
```

what I would like to do is to create a 3rd dataframe df3 with the following criteria:

Looking at the column `Index` of df2,

1) if there is 1 unique value I take the Start and End of the df[Index] and append it to df2 so that df3 is

```
df3
Out[7]: 
Index  Data1  Data2   Start   End     Duration 
    0      2      3       1     2            1
```

2) if there are multiple equal values (eg for Index =1) I take the Start of the first (ie. 4) and to the End I add 5 -> 9 and Duration will be 5

```
df3
Out[7]: 
Index  Data1  Data2   Start   End     Duration 
    0      2      3       1     2            1
    1      2      2       4     9            5
```

the other

```
df3
Out[7]: 
Index  Data1  Data2   Start   End     Duration 
    0      2      3       1     2            1
    1      2      2       4     9            5
    1      8      9      10    15            5
```

The final dataframe df3 should be:

```
df3
Out[7]: 
Index  Data1  Data2   Start   End     Duration 
    0      2      3       1     2            1
    1      2      2       4     9            5
    1      8      9      10    15            5
    2      1      1       7    12            5
    2      1      1      13    18            5
```

Here is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,1],[4,15,11],[7,22,15]],columns=['Start','End','Duration'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0,2,3],[1,2,2],[1,8,9],[2,1,1],[2,1,1]],columns=['Index','Data1','Data2'])
df2.index = df2['Index']
df3 = pd.DataFrame()

for index in df1.index:


    current_idx_df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1.loc[index].values.reshape(1,-1),columns=[df1.keys()])

    if np.sum(df2.index==index)==1:
        current_idx_df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2.loc[index].values.reshape(1,-1),columns=[df2.keys()])
        df3 = df3.append(pd.concat([current_idx_df1, current_idx_df2 ], axis=1))
        df3.reset_index(drop =True,inplace =True)
    else:
        current_idx_df2 = df2.loc[index]
        df3_temp = pd.concat([current_idx_df1, pd.DataFrame(current_idx_df2.iloc[0].values.reshape(1,-1),columns=[current_idx_df2.keys()]) ], axis=1)
        df3_temp['End'] = df3_temp['Start']+5
        df3_temp['Duration'] = 5

        df3 = df3.append(df3_temp)
        df3.reset_index(drop =True,inplace =True)

        for index2 in range(1,np.sum(df2.index==index)):

            df3_temp = pd.concat([current_idx_df1, pd.DataFrame(current_idx_df2.iloc[index2].values.reshape(1,-1),columns=[current_idx_df2.keys()]) ], axis=1)
            df3_temp['Start'] = df3['End'].values[-1]+1
            df3_temp['End'] = df3['End'].values[-1]+1+5
            df3_temp['Duration'] = 5
            df3 = df3.append(df3_temp)
            df3.reset_index(drop =True,inplace =True)
```

Comment: Will it always only be either 1 or 2 records? ISay for example there is a 3rd 1 index, would it then add another 5 (so in your example it would be start: 16 and end: 21)?

Comment: There can be more records, so as you said if there is a 3rd 1 index I would have to add another 5! :)

Comment: You lost me where you added 5 in 2). Why was that?

Comment: it is just a constant... basically I split the initial Start and End in windows of 5 seconds...